# 98 ford expedition stalls while driving or in park after it has ran for a while

Tags: engine, stall

'98 Ford Expedition

1. Symptoms started to occur a month ago.
2. Car stalls while driving or in park after 20 minutes
3. Can't turn on car for 24 hours.
4. If I unplug the battery for 20 minutes, I am able to run the engine for 20 minutes
5. After stalling and not unplugging the battery, I'll put in starter fluid and the car turns on immediately for 10 seconds before stalling(until starter fluid is gone).
6. There is spark
7. No noise clicking when turning key on after it stalls
8. No check engine light

What could be causing this?

Comment: Sometimes a bad crankshaft position sensor will do this. When engine gets warm it stops working. Many times it doesn't set a code. But if you can't hear the starter relay click when it won't start may negate this theory. That would indicate a bad primary ignition circuit. That could cause all symptoms. Do you have a lot of weight on your key chain?

Comment: I'd suspect the fuel pump. it may be failing to produce enough flow/pressure when it warms up.

Comment: Yeah, fuel pump makes more sense than crank sensor or ignition. I overlooked the starter fluid helping it run. Hooking up a fuel pressure gage would help determine this.

Comment: This is definitely a fueling issue, whether it's the pump or not remains to be seen. The reason I say that is because if the battery is disconnected, the vehicle will then run. I'm wondering if there is a relay which is overheating which goes to the fuel pump? Not saying the fuel pump *isn't* the issue, though. As @Jupiter stated, you need to check the fuel pressure, especially when its running. If you can catch the fuel pressure when the engine quits, it will give you a clue if this is where you need to be looking at.